# What is the best practices to save product quantity in an inventory database system

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a small database to manage my small business.

What is the best parasitic  to put my product stock quantity in the database ?
I already thought of two ways below

`product` table 
id,
code_bar,
weight,...

First approach `product_stock`
id, product `FK`, buying_price, quantity..

Example insert in the table  `product_stock` for the `product` number 1

id:1, product: **1** `FK` , buying_price:2, quantity:5

For this approach i simply declare that i have five items of the product 1

Second approach `product_stock`

Example insert in the table  `product_stock` for the `product` number 1

id:1, product: **1** `FK` , buying_price:2
id:2, product: **1** `FK` , buying_price:2
id:3, product: **1** `FK` , buying_price:2
id:4, product: **1** `FK` , buying_price:2
id:5, product: **1** `FK` , buying_price:2

In this approach I insert 5 lines to describe how many items I have for product 1

Answer (score 2):

The more typical method is to include a `quantity` column in the `product_stock` table.

However, under some circumstances, having row in the database for every item of stock can be useful.  After all, each item could have different characteristics:

- codes for tracking inventories
- dates when they are inserted
- supplier batches

If it is important to track such information, then a separate row per item could be helpful.